# No files in .net.minecraft

Tags: minecraft-modding, client

So, I've been trying to make a minecraft 1.11.2 client for minecraft. Thing is, the mcp/src/minecraft folder is empty, without any net files. The only error I had while decompiling was missing lwjgl 2.9.4, which does not exist. I have everything ready, but those files are missing, and thus I cannot code anything on my client(I am only using allowed mods.) This is a massive project I am taking for my favorite server, and I would like some help. Can anyone be kind and tell me how to fix this?

I have installed Optifine files for my client, and seems to have got about half of the files that I need.

What I need:
[image: What I need]

What I have:
[image: What I have]

As you can see, I am missing a lot of packages and have errors in most of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if we can help you in this one, because it' technically illegal to decompile Minecraft.

Comment: dang, but i thought it was allowed in the mc tutorial wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure, Mojang isn't very strict with these. You won't find it up on the internet though. Also, do you know Java?

Comment: @Bálint Decompilation is fine, it's the redistribution that is a problem.

Comment: @Balint I made a multiplayer game with Java, does that count?

Comment: Yeah sure, I just asked

Answer (score 1):

## Get Minecraft Forge

- Go here: http://files.minecraftforge.net/
- Download the MDK (latest is usually best for development)
- Follow the instructions for setup

There's no reason to decompile Minecraft yourself, the Forge team has already done everything that needs to be done and in a way that...

- Complies with the Minecraft EULA
- Insures compatibility
- Prevents modification of the vanilla source (see bullet 2)
- Allows *viewing* of the vanilla source (as a reference)
- Makes compiling your mod jar file easy

Comment: I am trying to make a client, not a mod, but thanks.

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo What do you mean by "client"?

Comment: A minecraft "hacked" client.

Comment: I am only putting in mods like optifine, fullbright, and bettersprint.

Comment: Also, the tutorial I am following is for 1.8, while I am working on 1.11.2.

Comment: Could that be the problem?

Comment: By the way, I use MCP to decompile the files.

Comment: I will try another way I found, combining forge decompiled stuff, and adding the getchangedsrc.bat file from MCP. Would that help?

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo A hacked client would be against the Minecraft EULA and virtually no one will help you do it.

Comment: It's not hacked, its like the Cosmic Client, with only Fullbright and bettersprint.

Comment: And yes, I found someone that can help me decompile minecraft.

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo If you're *adding someone else's* mods, you don't need to decompile at all. All you do is download the Forge installer, run it, and add the mods to the /mods folder.

Comment: omg, my question is what do you not understand about what I am doing. I am making a modded client, but including mods only like fullbright and bettersprint, and with keybinds.

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo Oh, so you're just violating the license and rights of *those mod authors.* I see.

Comment: what do you not get about the Minecraft EULA and the mod author's package? The src is free to use in Minecraft client projects, and For the EULA decompiling minecraft to create a modded client is in reality allowed, if the mods are not gamebreaking.